# Using bootstrap-datepicker with HTMX

Tags: post, events, bootstrap-datepicker, htmx

I am trying to use bootstrap-datepicker with HTMX.

On date change, I want to use the date as an argument with hx-post, but I have no idea how to approach this.

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcdtvr28/43/) with a working bootstrap-datepicker, and am trying to post to `/dateurl` on the [`changeDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/events.html#changedate) event, with the value of [`getDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/methods.html#getdate) method.

Am I even close? I was trying to use the [sortable](https://htmx.org/examples/sortable/) example on the htmx site as a starting point. I guess I'm not understanding how to actually *do* something when the event fires.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thank you for this jsfiddle, this way it was easy to play around.

I found this solution.

```
<input type="text" hx-trigger="change" hx-post="/dateurl"
       onchange="htmx.trigger(this, 'change')">
```

Not nice that the event needs to be dispatched manually. Maybe there is a better solution. But for me it did not work without the  `onchange` attribute.

Comment: It also fires immediately if you enter the first number of the year, and only once even if the date is changed later. I try to mitigate against  that by using delay:2s but it's not really reliable..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like bootstrap-datepicker doesn't propagate its events. Possibly because the event names weren't namespaced in any way, so events with generic names (such as "hide") were causing problems with other page elements.

My solution is to add an event handler to the datepicker which calls htmx.trigger directly.

```
$('.datepicker').on('changeDate', function(e) {
    htmx.trigger('#someHtmlElement', 'myChangeDateEvent')
})
```

And then on your element:

```
<div id="someHtmlElement" hx-trigger="myChangeDateEvent" hx-post="/myUrl" />
```